# Llamar a un metodo de Angular en una subscripcion al evento on de Socket.io

Tags: angular, ionic, socket.io

tengo una app en Ionic, que se conecta a un servidor socket, y quiero que al recibir un evento del servidor socket, ejecute un metodo de mi .ts.
En el servicio que se encarga de la relación con el socket tengo en el constructor:

```
super({
            url: environment.serverSocket,
            options: {
                query: {                   
                    idPersona: "0",           
                    grupo: "grupo1",
                }
            }

        });
 this.ioSocket.on('ALERTA_NUEVA', res => {
    this.outEven.emit(res);            
        }
            );
```

y en el .ts de la pagina tengo el constructor

```
this.socketService.outEven.subscribe(res => {
     //alert("Evento recibido desde el servidor socket, hay nueva alerta, refrescar el mapa");
      this.cargarListado("","");     
 } 
 );
```

Si descomento el "alert("Evento rec...", llama a cargar listado y el mapa se actualiza bien, si lo quito, llama a cargarListado pero en el mapa no aparece el marker.
Tengo que aclarar, que desde ionic inserto en la base de datos el registro que luego el cargar listado obtiene.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El socket puedes ponerlo en en el constructor ahí todo el tiempo estará activo de esa manera cuando el socket escuche lo que emite el servidor podrás ejecutar cualquier metodo

```
constructor(private storage: Storage,
private router: Router,
private modalController: ModalController,
private nav: NavController,  
private socket: Socket,   
) {
   this.socket.fromEvent('evento').sibscribe(res=>{
   this.metodo();
  })
} 

metodo(){
  //tu codigo
}
```